# How to assign value to a variable that's 'Get-Only'?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI. Currently when a user pinch zooms, the image goes back to regular position when finished. I'd like to have it so that when the user stops zooming in the picture, it stays zoomed in.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @GestureState var magnifyBy = CGFloat(1.0)
   @State var zoomIn = CGFloat(1.0)

    var magnification: some Gesture {
           MagnificationGesture()
               .updating($magnifyBy) { currentState, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = currentState
           }.onEnded{value in
               magnifyBy = value
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
           Circle()
               .frame(width: 100 * magnifyBy,
                      height: 100 * magnifyBy,
                      alignment: .center)
       }
}
```

> magnifyBy = value

Throws me an error: 
*Cannot assign to property: 'magnifyBy' is a get-only property*

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GestureState` is alive while gesture is active and must be used only inside this time-frame, updating correspondingly. After gesture finished the corresponding gesture state is reset to initial value. So to have changes persistent we need to store it separately.

Here is possible approach (tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @GestureState var magnifyBy = CGFloat(1.0)
    @State var zoomIn = CGFloat(1.0)
    
    var magnification: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .updating($magnifyBy) { value, gestureState, transaction in
                gestureState = value // gestureState is magnifyBy
        }.onEnded{ value in
            self.zoomIn *= value // < preserve last changes
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100 * magnifyBy * zoomIn, //after onEnded magnifyBy=1 again
                   height: 100 * magnifyBy * zoomIn,  
                   alignment: .center)
            .gesture(magnification)
    }
}
```

Please see for details on `GestureState` in official Apple article, [Adding Interactivity with Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/adding_interactivity_with_gestures). That rare case when documentation is full and good.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer here led me in the right direction, but I had a tricky interaction where I needed to update a `@StateObject` and so wasn't able to do the multiply in a `View`. The trick for me was to lazy-initialize the `@GestureState`. In case this helps someone else:

```
@StateObject var orbit: OrbitControls = OrbitControls() // Object I need to manipulate
@GestureState var preValue: (Float, Float)? = nil // (start, multiply)
var zoomGesture: some Gesture {
    MagnificationGesture()
        .updating($preValue) { value, gestureState, transaction in
            if gestureState == nil {
                gestureState = (orbit.radius, Float(value))
            } else {
                gestureState = (gestureState!.0, Float(value))
            }
            
        }.onChanged { value in
            guard let (start, mult) = preValue else {
                return
            }
            orbit.radius = start * mult // sync object state
        }
}
```